# creating a rank list by sorting an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, processing

I have two arrays where one array represents a collection of names and the other describes their associated marks.I wanted to sort the marks inside the array in ascending order, and then also the respective names related to the marks.

My aim is to create a rank list. I am using Processing to do this

```
float sum = 0;

String [] name = {"A", "B", "C", "D","E"};
float [] mark = {12, 2, 4, 6, 23};

void setup() {

  size(600, 600);
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
  background(225);
  fill(0);
  println(name.length); 
  for (int i =0; i<name.length; i++) {
    text(name[i] + ":"+ mark[i], 100, 100+i*50);
  }
}

/////// i wanted to sort it as E:23,    A:12,    D:6,     C:4,     B:2
```

It would be great if someone can help me with this. :)

Many thanks in advance,
Yousuf

Comment: Could you specify the language in your tags please?  Looks like C, but want to be sure...  Also, the various functions you are using look to be from a library - perhaps the Processing library?

Comment: Hi @MichaelDorgan I am using processing which is based on Java

Comment: Why are you using two `arrays`? [Maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) would be a much better choice

Answer (score 1):

You can make a data holder class implementing `Comparable`. I think you could also use a Map, like a hashMap.

Here a data holder class example:

```java
import java.util.Collections;

ArrayList <Data> d = new ArrayList<Data>();

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);

  d.add(new Data("A", 12));
  d.add(new Data("B", 2));
  d.add(new Data("C", 4));
  d.add(new Data("D", 6));
  d.add(new Data("E", 23));



  println("before sorting:\n" + d);

  //used reverseOrder as it goes decrescent, but you could just reverse
  //the "natural" order in the class it self. Exchange -1 and 1 in compareTo()
  // and use Collections.sort(d); here
  Collections.sort(d, Collections.reverseOrder());

  println("after sorting:\n" + d);
}


/////// i wanted to sort it as E:23,    A:12,    D:6,     C:4,     B:2


class Data implements Comparable {
  String name;
  int mark;

  Data(String _n, int _m) {
    name = _n;
    mark = _m;
  }

  // this sets the 'natural' order of Data
  @Override
    int compareTo(Object o) {
    Data other = (Data) o;

    if (other.mark > mark) {
      return -1;
    } else if (other.mark < mark) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }


  // this to get a nice looking output in console...
  @Override
    String toString() {
    return name + ":" + nf(mark, 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @v.k. the code works well. I now have to start learn about the maps :)

Comment: There is also [intDict](https://processing.org/reference/IntDict.html) which you can try